# Why I am unable to get the value using v-for?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I want to get the values of `"1999-00"` (which is a part of `stateStats` data property) through a function `xyz()` defined in computed property but I am unable to do so.

Does anyone have some idea about it?

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data(){
    return {
    stateStats : [{"State":"Andaman & Nicobar Islands","1999-00":"45"},
                             {"State":"Andhra Pradesh","1999-00":"27"},
                             {"State":"Arunachal Pradesh","1999-00":"9"}]
            }
        },
    computed:{
        xyz(){
          return this.stateStats['1999-00']
        }
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div v-for="x in xyz">
{{x}}
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `this.stateStats.map(x=>x['1999-00'])` or `this.stateStats.flatMap(x=>x['1999-00']||[])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Array `map` function to get the desired property out of your array of objects.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data(){
    return {
    stateStats : [{"State":"Andaman & Nicobar Islands","1999-00":"45"},
                             {"State":"Andhra Pradesh","1999-00":"27"},
                             {"State":"Arunachal Pradesh","1999-00":"9"}]
            }
        },
    computed:{
        xyz(){
          return this.stateStats.map(state => state["1999-00"]);
        }
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div v-for="x in xyz">
{{x}}
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `computed` property should be the same level as data.

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data(){
     return {/* whatever */}
  },
  computed : {
        xyz(){
          return this.stateStats.map( s => s['1999-00']);
        }
    }
});
```